# A theme dark/light toggle not loading desired state

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, themes

I am using local storage and when ever its in light mode it works fine, switches to dark mode and all is good, but it wont switch out, it will show the local variable color_mode as light, but it loads dark, which doesn't make any sense, and when I check local storage, it shows dark.

It should just switch in between the two modes and save the switched to mode after. I don't know if its anything obvious or a problem with my browser.

```js
var head;
var link;
var color_mode = "light";

function load() {
    const color_mode_stored = localStorage.getItem("color_mode");
    if (color_mode_stored != undefined)
        color_mode = color_mode_stored;
    else
        color_mode = "light";
    draw();
}

function draw () {
    head = document.getElementsByName("head")[0];
    link = document.createElement("link");

    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css";

    switch (color_mode){
        case 'dark':
            link.href = "dark_mode.css";
            break;
        case 'light':
            link.href = "light_mode.css";
            break;
    }

    head.appendChild(link);
}

function color_change () {

    if (color_mode == 'light'){
        color_mode = 'dark';
    }
    else {
        color_mode = 'light';
    }
    localStorage.setItem("color_mode", color_mode);

    console.log("yay", color_mode);

    document.location.reload();

}

load();
```

Comment: There are better ways to do this than loading stylesheets.  Have a look a [prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) which has some easy to follow examples.

Comment: Or even put the CSS into one stylesheet and use a class to toggle between, light, dark, and default?

Comment: There is a mistake in your code.  getElementsByName returns form elements with a matching name attribute. For head you need to use getElementsByTagName (note Tag).  Seems to work if you fix that mistake.  See your code working here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgatm9uq/1/)